# Drinking freshly squeezed lemon juice in warm water first thing in the morning

Tags: juice

I've read this in a detoxifying book, its suppose to help the liver.

Then I've seen maybe one or two women celebrities saying they stick with this regime. They also stick with drinking fresh fruit juice afterwards as breakfast.

What do you think?

Comment: I think I've read the same book and actually tried it for a while. I couldn't really tell a difference, but then again the diet wasn't meant for me :-) In my case the book was called ["You are what you eat" by Gillian McKeith](http://www.gillianmckeith.info/you-are-what-you-eat-2)

Comment: In general, I run screaming from any celebrity endorsed behavior. :)

Comment: Actually the diet has quite some similarities with a Paleo Diet, so its not that bad @Christopher

Comment: I've been doing it for quite a while now, probably around 6 months already. Im not sure how to measure any progress though (like you said Ivo). Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Save a lemon tree or two (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urine_therapy#Auto-urine_drinking_and_meditation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My boyfriend and I have been drinking lemon juice with warm water first thing in the morning for many years now. Even when we travel, we purchase lemons once we arrive at our destination so we're able to continue this practice.

I'm sure there are quite a few books out there that support it, but speaking first hand, I can tell you that it's very beneficial to the body. Lemon juice (freshly squeezed) and warm water in the morning is a great digestive aid because it stimulates the liver to produce bile. This helps with digestion and also helps to get your bowels moving.

Lemon juice is also full of antioxidants (Vitamin C) and bioflavanoids, which we know have been shown to reduce the risk of cancer and to boost immunity.

Comment: I wonder though what it is that makes this help with digestion or how it helps your bowels get moving. Care to look for some sources?